# Java - How to improve rendering when printing?

Tags: java, html, css, swing, printing

I'm using CSSBox to render a web page HTML and CSS and then print it. The application must deal with specific sites. The idea is to make some sites that aren't designed to be printable actually print and look readable. This is done by removing menus, headers, etc. centering content, overriding some styles.

My current approach is to render the site to a component that is part of the CSSBox API called BrowserCanvas. I adjust the width of the canvas for each supported site to ensure that paragraphs look good in each case. This BrowserCanvas descends from JPanel and has the paint methods that I use to render it to the printer Graphics object.

The problem is that the printer canvas is usually huge, think 300 ppp, 600 ppp, etc. What I'm done now is set a RenderingHints to force Bicubic interpolation to scale the document up to fill all space in the printed page.

The problem is that you can see that the documents is like an up scaled screenshot, and does not look very good in the printed page.

Is there a better approach?

**Print Method**

Access to printer is obtained by the PrinterJob class.

Then I override the BrowserCanvas print method that accepts a page number. According to that number I set scale and translation on the graphic object, taking care that if the last line of text cannot fit entirely in the page it is moved to the next page. Then I call super.print() passing as parameter the graphic object that has all the scaling and translation applied.

I thought the scaling would be soft, like doing everything happen at a higher resolution, like font sizes, but it looks more like draw everything in a base resolution then upscaling the result to the desired one.

Example of a modified page (using the CSSBox documentation site for testing):

page 1
[image: out-0.png]

---

page 2
[image: out-1.png]

Comment: How are you getting this to print at all? I'm not understanding that part of the question.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I will update question. I'm extending BrowserCanvas to implement Printable, then overriding print, then applying some scaling and redering hints, then calling BrowserCanvas.print. Results are not satisfactory at all, printed page is very pixelated. Test platform is Linux.

Comment: The print method I overriding is the one that accept the page number, after applying hints, scaling and translation I call super class print method that only accept a graphic object, passing the one I setted all those properties.

Comment: Very late, but have you tried changing the MediaSpec "resolution" field? See http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/manual/#media and http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/jstyleparser/api/cz/vutbr/web/css/MediaSpec.html#resolution

Comment: @NelsonMenezes Yes, I tried that but It seems the problem is with the printer canvas resolution. I tried the java program in a Windows PC and the canvas is a lot bigger. In Windows It's possible to increase the resolution as the configuration dialog displayed is the OS dialog. But in Linux Java has It's own printer config dialog, with less options than the OS one. It does not let you change resolution or quality.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could try rendering a new printable webpage instead.Since you are overriding the styles maybe you could add new media queries or a print stylesheet like this:

```
@media print { 
 /* All your print styles go here */
 #header, #footer, #nav { display: none !important; } 
}
```

Or,In the old way:

```
<link href="/print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" />
```

and then you can use the print dialog from any browser of the OS

Comment: I already gave up on creating an app that automates the process. Now I just modify the styles of the page prior to print. Maybe I can write a browser extension that do It automatically. There is Readability, but It's mean to optimize pages for mobile not for printing, fonts are too big. It lets you adjust the font size but even the smallest is too big.